# How to set up a separate wifi SSID with VLAN on OpenWRT?

Tags: openwrt

There is a TP-Link TL-WR740N router with OpenWrt 18.06.9 installed. The setup is: 1 SSID, bridged with switch and WAN port, so the router acts like an AP (DHCP disabled, just "converting ethernet to wifi").

With Unifi APs you can add another SSID with VLAN (so 1 SSID will be wihtout VLAN and 1 SSID will be with VLAN). How to do the same with OpenWRT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in this case (TP-Link TL-WR740N router with OpenWrt 18.06.9 installed) is: there is **no way to make simultaniously tagged and untagged VLANs on eth0** (Switch ports), so you **cannot use untagged VLAN and tagged VLAN**, but: you **can use eth1** (WAN port) with "Software VLAN" (just adding eth1.N to bridge), this way you can use eth0 (Switch ports) as a switch, connected to either untagged OR tagged VLAN.
Also, if you have only tagged VLANs, you can use any eth0 port to bridge it with different SSIDs. More here: https://forum.openwrt.org/t/how-to-set-up-a-separate-wifi-ssid-with-vlan-on-openwrt/95375/31